# Java Using Generic Class object with different objects

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance

I think that this is a simple question to answer and if it's been asked already, please forgive the repeat.

I'm writing a graph analysis tool using the JUNG-2.0.1 toolset (very cool stuff if you haven't used before).  Anyway, I have the following class structure in my java program.

```
 public edge() {}
 public vehicle() {}
 public car() extends vehicle {}
 public truck() extends vehicle {}
```

Now, when writing the code for the graph viewer class the header is written as

```
 public customgraphviewer<node, edge>() {}
```

if I write the class header as

```
 public customgraphviewer<vehicle, edge>() {}
```

would it accept either car or truck objects?  I think that it will because both classes inherit from the same parent are there the same type.  Am I correct or is there something else that I should do.

Laurence -

Comment: You have to learn the generic type variable declaration syntax. Declaring `public class Something<Vehicle, Edge>` creates two **new type variables** named `Vehicle` and `Edge`. These types have absolutely nothing to do with your `Vehicle` and `Edge`.

Comment: also, the class structure you provided is *not* Java; in Java you use `edge()` etc for constructor, not for class declaration. also, since when a lowercase name is a JLS-compliant class name? IFTFY - if you're using some kind of app-specific markup, don't mark it as general "java", otherwise use valid Java conventions for your code. It's unclear what you're really asking here and if you have a minimal understanding of the subject at hand.

Comment: I'm rolling back my changes until someone can explain to me *what is really asked here*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use a wildcard argument, and narrowing it down to known superclass:

```
public customgraphviewer<? extends vehicle, edge>() {}
```

Comment: What is this? No part of that line of code is valid Java.